# Change IP Address using libnm and glib

Tags: c++, glib, networkmanager

I'm trying to use libnm to change the ip address of my interface inside a C++ application, but I cannot find a good example around. For now I was able to get the device handler and ask for connections.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NMClient *       client;
    GError *         error = NULL;
    const GPtrArray *connections;
    int              i;

    if (!(client = nm_client_new(NULL, &error))) 


    if (!nm_client_get_nm_running(client)) {
        g_message("Error: Can't obtain connections: NetworkManager is not running.");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Find the device
    NMDevice* device = nm_client_get_device_by_iface (client, "eno1");

    NMDeviceState state = nm_device_get_state (device);
    if(state == NM_DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVATED)
    {
        NMActiveConnection* connection = nm_device_get_active_connection(device);
        NMIPConfig * ipConfig = nm_active_connection_get_ip4_config(connection);

        //what now?
    }
    else
    {
        const GPtrArray* availableConnections = nm_device_get_available_connections(device);

        for (i = 0; i < availableConnections->len; i++)
        {
            //How do I iterate through available connections, and how can I add an ip address and activate it?   
        }
    }

    g_object_unref(client);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It is not clear what I can do with the connections, how should I modify them (I want to set dhcp, or fixed ip address with minimal configuration), how should I activate a connection and store it.
I was not able to retrieve a good example for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you find the profile (`NMRemoteConnection`) that you want to activate, you can activate it with `nm_client_activate_connection_async()`.

See the libnm documentation [here](https://developer.gnome.org/libnm/unstable/NMClient.html#nm-client-activate-connection-async).

Now, you'll notice that `nm_client_activate_connection_async()` is only asynchronous API. That means, to use it you must iterate the [`GMainContext`](https://developer.gnome.org/programming-guidelines/stable/main-contexts.html.en) until the callback returns. In general, D-Bus is inherently asynchronous because you send messages back and forth. That means, synchronous API on top of that [has problems](https://smcv.pseudorandom.co.uk/2008/11/nonblocking/).

Note that the activate connection callback gets invoked, the device barely started to activate. You only get the `NMActiveConnection`, which is a handle to the activation you made. The device not yet fully up. What "fully up" means depends on how you interpret it. A common interpretation would be to say that the device's state progresses all the way to `NM_DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVATED`. If you want to wait for that, you would subscribe signals and iterate the `GMainContext` further until the activation either succeeded or failed.

See also [what nmcli does](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/blob/a21fdd42376233eee5ad2c75338322ad4641de11/clients/cli/connections.c#L2736).